# c# HMACSHA256 encription to HMACSHA256 in php

Tags: c#, php

I am trying to generating the hash in PHP but not getting the same output as I get from c# in my code so which encryption algorithm(or what should I change in my code) should I use. the code that I am using in PHP and c#-

php code

```
<?php

$date = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s\Z");
$ServiceAPIKey = "abc";
    $ServiceAPIPassword = "def";
    $serviceId = "1234";

        $message = $serviceId.$date;

$signature = $ServiceAPIKey.":".base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $message, $ServiceAPIPassword,true));
echo $signature;
?>
```

c# code

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dateString = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("u");
var serviceId = "1234";
string ServiceAPIKey = "abc";
string ServiceAPIPassword = "def";
var signature = "";

        var signature = CalculateSignature(ServiceAPIKey, ServiceAPIPassword, message);
        Console.WriteLine(signature );
    }

    public static string CalculateSignature(string ServiceAPIKey, string ServiceAPIPassword, string message)
    {
        string hashString =string.Empty;

        using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ServiceAPIPassword)))
        {
            var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
            hashString = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        }

        hashString = ServiceAPIKey + ":" + hashString;
        return hashString;
    }
}
```

I expect this - `abc:DWe/a/aZrapRALbgZLJzx6m1ndaM7RP1hRxCFyBlZo0=` o/p that I am getting from mine php code.
php o/p that I am getting is `abc:14w9U25MPeZ8Wg4lavtrG+IN/UyTe68wEV/Z1fkLLhc=`

Comment: Does PHP even use UTF8 as its encoding? Have you tried `Encoding.Unicode`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make same `date` on both c# and PHP. if you are using this `$date = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s\Z");` in `$message = $serviceId.$date;` then this `H:i:s` will vary on both while executing. Use same date only on both the language then try with following code in php

```
<?php
$date = gmdate("Y-m-d"); // 2019-05-15 use the same in C#
$ServiceAPIKey = "abc";
$ServiceAPIPassword = "def";
$serviceId = "1234";

$message = $serviceId.$date;

//$message = strtolower($message); //Not needed
$signature = hash_hmac("sha256", utf8_encode($message), utf8_encode($ServiceAPIPassword), false);
// Convert hexadecimal string to binary and then to base64
$signature = hex2bin($signature);
$signature = base64_encode($signature);

echo $ServiceAPIKey.":".$signature . "<br>\n";
?>
```